# How to get Item Price after Selection from select2 Dropdown list in dot net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I have a form from which I select item name from select2 dropdown list.
I need support to retrieve item price in the price input after selection from the list

Here my Html

```
   <div class="col-4">
                    <select class="form-control" id="itemslist" asp-for="Expiree.ItemId" asp-items="Model.Itemslist">
                        <option value="SSS"></option>
                    </select>
                    <input class="form-control" type="hidden" asp-for="Expiree.ItemName"  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">
                    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Expiree.ItemPrice" />
                </div>
```

here my script section

```
@section scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#itemslist").select2();
        });
        $("body").on("change", "#itemslist", function () {
            $("#Expiree_ItemName").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
        });
    </script>
```

here my page model

```
public class CreateeModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public CreateeModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        public SelectList Itemslist { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public Expiree Expiree { get; set; }
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            this.Itemslist = new SelectList(_db.Items, "Id", "Name", "Price");


            return Page();
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            _db.Expiree.Add(Expiree);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
    }
```

this my item model

```
public class Items
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
```

here my problem, I need to fetch item price directly after selection to push it to my database

[![][1]][1]

Dear@Rena
attached front and Back Gif

```
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
```

my page view

```
<form method="post">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <select class="form-control" id="itemslist" asp-for="Expiree.ItemId" asp-items="Model.Itemslist">
                        <option value="SSS"></option>
                    </select>
                    <input class="form-control" type="hidden"asp-for="Expiree.ItemPrice"  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">
                    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Expiree.ItemPrice" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">

                    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Expiree.ItemQ" />
                </div>
               
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-5 offset-4">
                <partial name="_CreateAndBackToListButton" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@section scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#itemslist").select2();
        });
        $("body").on("change", "#itemslist", function () {
            $("#Expiree_ItemName").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Createe?handler=Price&id=" + $(this).find("option:selected").val(),
            success: function (res) {
                $("#Expiree_ItemPrice").val(res);
            }
        })
        });
    </script>
}
```

my page Model

```
public class CreateeModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public CreateeModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        public SelectList Itemslist { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public Expiree Expiree { get; set; }
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            this.Itemslist = new SelectList(_db.Items, "Id", "Name",3);


            return Page();
        }
        public JsonResult OnGetPrice(int id)
        {
            var price = _db.Items.Where(a => a.Id == id).Select(a => a.Price).First();
            
            return new JsonResult(price);
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
       
            _db.Expiree.Add(Expiree);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
    }
```

```
[![enter image description here][4]][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE34t.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UkDZ.gif
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyYCp.gif
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhqVU.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may misunderstand the `Selectlist`, you can see the `Selectlist` constructor's definition here `public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, object selectedValue)`, the last parameter means selected value. It is used to point out the dropdownlist selected value.  And the value should be any of your `Id` which is the dataValueFied. It cannot bind to the `Price` property.

For your scenario, you can add an `onchange` event and make ajax call to get the corresponding `Price` by `ItemId` or `ItemName`:

`Createe.cshtml` located in `Pages` folder:

```
<form method="Post">
<div class="col-4">
    <select class="form-control" id="itemslist" asp-for="Expiree.ItemId" asp-items="Model.Itemslist">
        <option value="SSS"></option>
    </select>
    <input class="form-control" type="hidden" asp-for="Expiree.ItemName"  />
</div>
<div class="col-1">
      <input class="form-control" asp-for="Expiree.ItemPrice" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>

@section scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#itemslist").select2();
        });
        $("body").on("change", "#itemslist", function () {
            $("#Expiree_ItemName").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"/Createe?handler=Price&id="+$(this).find("option:selected").val(),
                success:function(res)
                {                     
                    $("#Expiree_ItemPrice").val(res);
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

Createe.cshtml.cs:

```
public class CreateeModel : PageModel
{
    //...

    public SelectList Itemslist { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public Expiree Expiree { get; set; }        
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        this.Itemslist = new SelectList(_db.Items, "Id", "Name", 3);
        return Page();
    }

    public JsonResult OnGetPrice(int Id)
    {
        var price = _db.Items.Where(a=>a.Id==Id).Select(a=>a.Price).First();
        return new JsonResult(price);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        //.....
        return RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
}
```

You can check the gif for the process of the demo, the only difference is that I hard coded the database data for easy testing:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your support but i still can't fitch item price after selection ...

Comment: Please share your code. And F12 in browser to check if  Console contains any error? Also what's the result of your `OnGetPrice` method?

Comment: Hi @Mohamedshaker , I have shared the gif for the whole process, you can also check it.

Comment: Dear @rena ajax call id well but not passed to OnGetPrice method as showed in below attached back anfd front GIF------https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-sws6fVOFUAr6YwarY4OrMcjLIbK6Vwe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uPNqzQUnMMOHkK_YKmDpho5BQeu5h1tT/view?usp=sharing----also attached my page view and model

Comment: Sorry I cannot use `ZIP Extractor`, please edit your original post.

Comment: i just Edit it i think the problem in GetPrice model not fetch the id from ajax to start filtering and get the price as the debugger not stopped in any stage

Comment: Can you set breakpoint to OnGetPrice method? And check `$(this).find("option:selected").val()` by console.log($(this).find("option:selected").val()).

Comment: i set breakpoint to OnGetprice method but not affect the code run without debug---attached image from browser console get id value but still price not get

Comment: Hi, actually it make 404 error which means your ajax url is not correct. My Createe.cshtml located in Pages folder so the url is : `/Createe?xxxxx`, where is your Createe.cshtml?

Comment: Hi i tried to change URL to "/Expire/Createe.cshtml?handler=Price&id="---the result is error 404----then i copied the createe.cshtml to pages folder and change the URL to "/Createe.cshtml?handler=Price&id=" but get the same error 404---can i share you my full project to support me--thanks

Comment: Hi, Of course you can share the full project. pls be careful and remember do not share your personal messages . BTW, do you add `endpoints.MapRazorPages();` in your `app.UseEndpoints`?

Comment: Hi @Mohamedshaker, it should be `/Expire/Createe?handler=Price&id=3` instead of `/Expire/Createe.cshtml?handler=Price&id=`.

Comment: Hi @Mohamedshaker, any update?

Comment: Hi @Rena Excellent well done...thanks very very very much for your support